# Как вывести объект в списке в строчном виде?

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть код:

```
class Object:
def __init__(self, name, value):
    self.name = name
    self.value = value

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name) + ": " + str(self.value)


# Список - массив ссылок на объекты
test_list = [Object("Name", 32), 3405, "hello"]
print(test_list)  # Выводит - [<__main__.Object object at 0x00000139E226FFD0>, 3405, 'hello']
test_list = list(map(str, test_list))
print(test_list) # Выводит - ['Name: 32', '3405', 'hello']
```

Вопрос:

1. Почему объект не приводится к строке, хотя реализован метод **str**? Отдельно, не в списке, объект успешно приводится к строке ('Name: 32')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что при выводе на печать контейнера (спасибо GrAnd за уточнение) используется другой метод, который нужно реализовать в классе:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Про сортировку у вас вопрос не дописан, но там тоже нужно реализовать некоторые методы класса. См. [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering), в современном питоне достаточно реализовать всего пару методов - один сравнения и один равенства и задекорировать класс специальным декоратором, остальное питон сделает сам.

Comment: Вообще интересно... `print()` на самом деле использует `__str__`. Но если на печать выводится контейнер, то `__repr__`. Давным давно было [предложение](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3140/) привести всё к единому виду, но оно было отклонено.

Comment: @GrAnd Хм, прикольно, да. Если сделать `print(*test_list)`, то будет использован `__str__`, забавно.

Comment: Вопрос с сортировкой я решил самостоятельно, но спасибо за уточнение. При изменении __str__ на __repr__ всё успешно заработало, спасибо!

Comment: Лучше реализовать оба метода, т.е. добавить тот, который я написал,  к вашему :)